# How to create and display an animated GIF in Shiny?

Tags: shiny, gif, gganimate

I'm able to load a saved file as an image but unable to use `gganimate` to do it directly. Alternate ways of rendering GIFs would be nice to know but knowing how to render `gganimate` specifically would really solve my problem.

```
library(gapminder)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(gganimate)
theme_set(theme_bw())

ui <- basicPage(
    plotOutput("plot1")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
        p = ggplot(gapminder, aes(gdpPercap, lifeExp, size = pop, color = continent, frame = year)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_log10()

       gg_animate(p)

    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 11):

Now that there's a newer breaking version of `gganimate`, @kt.leap's answer is deprecated. Here's what worked for me with the new `gganimate`:

```
library(gapminder)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(gganimate)
theme_set(theme_bw())

ui <- basicPage(
    imageOutput("plot1"))

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$plot1 <- renderImage({
    # A temp file to save the output.
    # This file will be removed later by renderImage
    outfile <- tempfile(fileext='.gif')

    # now make the animation
    p = ggplot(gapminder, aes(gdpPercap, lifeExp, size = pop, 
      color = continent)) + geom_point() + scale_x_log10() +
      transition_time(year) # New

    anim_save("outfile.gif", animate(p)) # New

    # Return a list containing the filename
     list(src = "outfile.gif",
         contentType = 'image/gif'
         # width = 400,
         # height = 300,
         # alt = "This is alternate text"
         )}, deleteFile = TRUE)}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I get an error message: "animation of gg objects not supported"

Comment: @jlp This code still works for me. Check that you have everything updated, including the `gifski` package. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58336048/error-in-animate-default-animation-of-gg-objects-not-supported

Answer (score 5):

I was dealing with the same issue and found only your question and no answers... But the way you phrased it reminded me that `renderPlot` is finicky:

> it won’t send just any image file to the browser – the image must be generated by code that uses R’s graphical output device system. Other methods of creating images can’t be sent by `renderPlot()`... The solution in these cases is the `renderImage()` function. [source](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/images.html)

Modifying the code from that article gives you the following:

```
library(gapminder)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(gganimate)
theme_set(theme_bw())

ui <- basicPage(
    imageOutput("plot1"))

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$plot1 <- renderImage({
    # A temp file to save the output.
    # This file will be removed later by renderImage
    outfile <- tempfile(fileext='.gif')

    # now make the animation
    p = ggplot(gapminder, aes(gdpPercap, lifeExp, size = pop, 
      color = continent, frame = year)) + geom_point() + scale_x_log10()

    gg_animate(p,"outfile.gif")

    # Return a list containing the filename
     list(src = "outfile.gif",
         contentType = 'image/gif'
         # width = 400,
         # height = 300,
         # alt = "This is alternate text"
         )}, deleteFile = TRUE)}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back. Life got in the way. Your solution requires saving a file to the disk. I already mentioned in my question that I'm able to load saved files so this doesn't add much.

Comment: As far as I understand, it doesn't save the file to disk. It's a file that is used by `renderImage`, as opposed to the `renderPlot` framework. So it'll render `gganimate` directly, without having to do anything further, but it does so using `renderImage`.