# Error in animate.default() : animation of gg objects not supported

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

Getting error message `Error in animate.default() : animation of gg objects not supported` when running the following (from tutorial [here](http://r-statistics.co/Top50-Ggplot2-Visualizations-MasterList-R-Code.html))

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)
library(gapminder)
theme_set(theme_bw())  # pre-set the bw theme.

g <- ggplot(gapminder, aes(gdpPercap, lifeExp, size = pop, frame = year)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(aes(group = year), 
              method = "lm", 
              show.legend = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~continent, scales = "free") +
  scale_x_log10()  # convert to log scale

animate(g, interval=0.2)
```

How can the animation be rendered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this may have to do with the newer version of `gganimate` and [change in API](https://gganimate.com/index.html).

> This is the second iteration of the gganimate package. The first,
>   developed by David Robinson had a very different API, and relied on
>   specifying animation frame membership inside aes() blocks in the
>   geom_*() calls. This approach was easy to grasp, but essentially
>   limited in capabilities and has thus been abandoned for a more
>   thorough grammar.
>
> Code written for the old API will not work with this gganimate version
>   and there will not come a future support for it. If you wish to
>   continue using the old API then avoid upgrading gganimate. If you’ve
>   already upgraded and wish to downgrade, the latest version of the old
>   API is available as a GitHub release.

If you wish to use the old API it is available [here](https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate/releases/tag/v0.1.1). If you are using or plan to use version >1.0.0, then would not use `frame` in `aes()` as previously done. To get the same example functional try:

```
ggplot(gapminder, aes(gdpPercap, lifeExp, size = pop)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(aes(group = year), 
              method = "lm", 
              show.legend = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~continent, scales = "free") +
  scale_x_log10() +
  transition_manual(year)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, using the same dataset. All I did was add this to my code:

```html
gapminder = data.frame(gapminder)
```

The animate function was working perfectly.
Here is the animated plot code:

```html
p1 <- ggplot(gapminder, aes(gdpPercap, lifeExp, size = pop, colour = country)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.7, show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = country_colors) +
  scale_size(range = c(2, 12)) +
  scale_x_log10() +
  facet_wrap(~continent) +
  labs(title = 'Year: {frame_time}', x = 'GDP per capita', y = 'Life expectancy') +
  transition_time(year) +
  ease_aes('linear')

#set_config( config( ssl_verifypeer = 0L ) )
#devtools::install_github("dgrtwo/gganimate")

animate(p1)
```