# How can I plot a selection from a Shiny selectInput widget in ggplot using flexdashboard

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

It is my understanding Shiny's selectInput widget returns a character vector.  I am unclear as to why the user input cannot be passed to ggplot as a column name.  Naturally this fails to plot as desired.

This is my yaml.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

> Blockquote ---
> title: "Untitled"
> output:
> flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
> orientation: rows
> runtime: shiny

---

```
library(tidyverse)
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
```

```
spy <- tibble(Date  = as.Date(c("2020-12-28", "2021-12-30", "2022-03-15")),
              Happy = c(8.25, 12.48, 11.52 ),
              Glad  = c(4, 5, 7 ) )

  

shiny::selectInput(
             inputId = "select_data",
             label   = "Select Data",
             choices = c("Happy", "Glad"),
             selected = "Happy"                             
   )
```

```
renderPlot({
  
   ggplot(spy, aes(   1:3,  input$select_data) )   +
     geom_line()

})
```

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHEWu.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIWrY.png
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to connect user input with gganimate graph in R shiny?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71810703/how-to-connect-user-input-with-gganimate-graph-in-r-shiny)

Comment: You can use the data pronoun: `renderPlot({ ggplot(spy, aes(x = Date,  .data[[input$select_data]]) )  + geom_line() })`

Comment: `aes_string(...)` instead of `aes(...)` should work

Comment: All 3 worked!  Thank you for the quick round of responses.  - 1) !!sym(input$select_data])), 2)  aes_string(...) , and 3)  .data[[input$select_data]]