# Shinyapp mapping by species and color

Tags: r, shiny, mapping, shinyapps

I should create in my shiny app this conditions:
In the UI setup add a selectInput field: the first argument is
the name (how to access the selection in the server setup, we will
call this "species"), the second argument is the label (appears on
the app), and the third argument should list the choices: here we
want to choose between the three different species (can you
obtain the three choices from the data directly?).

I receive this error in my code:
I receive this error:
Error in match.arg(position) : 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector

**CODE**:

```
library(shiny)
library(palmerpenguins)
library(ggplot2)

# Define UI for application that draws a plot
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
titlePanel("Penguins"),

# Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId = "VarX",
      label = "Select X-axis Variable",
      choices =  list("flipper_length_mm","species","island", 
                      "bill_length_mm","bill_depth_mm","body_mass_g",
                      "sex","year")),
      selectInput(inputId = "VarY",
                  label = "Select Y-axis Variable",
                  choices = list("flipper_length_mm","species","island", 
                  "bill_length_mm","bill_depth_mm","body_mass_g",
                  "sex","year")),
      selectInput(
        inputId = "varColor",
        label = "Color",
        choices = c("species"),
        selected = "species")),
 selectInput(
      inputId = "species",
                label = "select species",
                choices = list("adelie","gentoo","chinstrap")),
    
    # Show a plot 
    mainPanel(
       plotOutput("scatter")
    )
)
)

#Define server logic required to draw a scatter
server <- function(input, output) {
  pengu <- reactive({ggplot(penguins,
                            aes(y = bill_depth_mm, x = bill_length_mm))+
      geom_point(aes(color = .data[[input$species]]))})

    output$scatter <- renderPlot({
      pengu()
 


    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: The parentheses after `sidebarPanel` don't close correctly, they should close after the last `selectInput`. However, I'm also not sure what you want to select with the species `selectInput`, because there are no different columns for the species, just one which you could filter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to connect user input with gganimate graph in R shiny?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71810703/how-to-connect-user-input-with-gganimate-graph-in-r-shiny)

Comment: Thanks, I do not have the error anymore now, still have to figure out how to solve the taks. I forgot to add a second part of the task: In the server setup update your plotting code: we will make the
plot such that the selected species gets highlighted. Instead of
mapping species to color we will check if the species is equal to
the selected one (this information is stored in input$species)
instead. You might want to change the color scale here: not
selected should be gray, selected in color.