# gganimate and plotly do not render on rmarkdown with shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, ggplotly, gganimate

A rmarkdown does not render plots made with gganinate and plotly. The app should have a select input box to choose each plot.I saw
that renderImage() and renderPlotly() should be used. How will I incorporate these functions? What is the better way of writing this code. Thanks

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  skin = "red",
  dashboardHeader(disable = TRUE),
  dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      box(
        width = 8,
        title = "Chart", background = "maroon", solidHeader = TRUE,
        plotOutput("plot", height = 300)
      ),
      box(
        width = 4,
        background = "aqua", solidHeader = TRUE,
        selectInput("data", "Choose visual",
          choices = c("barchart", "histogram", "boxplot", "bars", "sbars"), selected =
            "barchart"
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    if (input$data == "barchart") {

      # HIV status disclosure with marital status
      myplot <- ggplot(hiv, aes(x = disclosure_status, fill = marital_status)) +
        geom_bar() +
        transition_states(marital_status)

      myplot <- myplot + enter_fade() + exit_fade()
    }


    if (input$data == "histogram") {

      # Distribution of age with marital status
      myplot <- ggplot(hiv, aes(age, fill = marital_status)) +
        geom_histogram()

      myplot <- ggplotly(myplot)
    }

    if (input$data == "boxplot") {

      # Disclosure, age and marital status
      myplot <- ggplot(hiv, aes(x = disclosure_status, y = age, fill = marital_status)) +
        geom_boxplot() +
        transition_states(marital_status) +
        shadow_wake(wake_length = 1, alpha = FALSE, wrap = FALSE)
    }

    if (input$data == "bars") {

      # Subset the column for contraception
      fp2 <- hiv %>%
        select(family_planning) %>%
        count(family_planning)

      # Pictorial count of family planning
      myplot <- ggplot(fp2, aes(family_planning, n, fill = family_planning)) +
        geom_col() +
        geom_text(aes(label = n, vjust = -0.5)) +
        theme_minimal() +
        theme(legend.position = "none", axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 0)) +
        labs(title = "Histogram of types of contraceptive")
    }

    if (input$data == "sbars") {

      # Family planning and pregnancy
      myplot <- ggplot(data = hiv, aes(x = planPreg, fill = family_planning)) +
        geom_bar(position = "dodge") +
        facet_wrap(~family_planning)

      ggplotly(myplot)
    }

    myplot
  })
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You might want to check plotly's [animation capabilities](https://plotly.com/r/animations/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither `gganimate` nor `plotly` will work with `renderPlot` and `plotOutput`. `plotly` requires `renderPlotly` and `plotlyOutput` while for following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35421923/how-to-create-and-display-an-animated-gif-in-shiny/53105252) you could use `renderImage` and `imageOutput` for `gganimate`.

To condition the type of output via a `selectInput` one option would be to use `uiOutput` and `renderUI`.

Using some fake data and a `radioButtons` instead of a `selectInput`:

```r
library(shiny)
library(gganimate)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  radioButtons("data", "Choose", choices = c("plotly", "gganimate")),
  uiOutput("foo")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plotly <- renderPlotly({
    ggpenguins <- qplot(bill_length_mm, body_mass_g,
      data = palmerpenguins::penguins, color = species
    )
    ggplotly(ggpenguins)
  })

  output$gganimate <- renderImage(
    {
      anim <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) +
        geom_point(aes(color = gear)) +
        transition_states(gear, transition_length = 2, state_length = 1) +
        enter_fade() +
        exit_fade()
      anim_save("outfile.gif", animate(anim)) # New

      # Return a list containing the filename
      list(src = "outfile.gif", contentType = "image/gif")
    },
    deleteFile = TRUE
  )

  output$foo <- renderUI({
    if (input$data == "plotly") {
      plotlyOutput("plotly")
    } else {
      imageOutput("gganimate")
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3089
```

[image]